# Truffle overwrite MetaMask web3 wrong msg.sender address

Tags: contract-development, truffle, metamask

Considering this contract :

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract Test {

    function Test() {
        // constructor
    }

    function getMsgSender() constant returns (address account) {
        account = msg.sender;
    }

}
```

When I deploy my app with `truffle serve` and use chrome dbg and run

```
var t = Test.deployed();
t.getMsgSender().then(function(res) {
    console.log(res.toString())
});
```

I expect to received my accounts[0] but **I received another address which I'm not aware of**.

**EDIT**
As Roland Kofler said on the comment section, it seems that the injected web3 form MetaMask is somehow overwrite by web3 provided by truffle.
When I open another tab and play with the injected web3 from MetaMask :

```
var testContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getMsgSender","outputs":[{"name":"account","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"}]);
var test = testContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x606060405234610000575b5b5b60bd8061001a6000396000f30060606040526000357c0100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000900463ffffffff1680637a6ce2e114603c575b6000565b3460005760466088565b604051808273ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200191505060405180910390f35b60003390505b905600a165627a7a7230582010d921743656299a4367d73c9ad8249848967aebebbc91093aeb9dce6f74a3380029', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
test.getMsgSender(function(error, result) {
    console.log(result.toString()) // Works, accounts[0] as result
});
```

Is there a way to make things works with truffle ? Where does the address I get from the overwriting cames from ?

Comment: you probably overwrite web3 with metamask, while having your own localhost geth or the other way around, or you are on a different network, like testnet, mainnet etc.

Comment: For sure I'm on the same network (ropsten) and my MetaMask is configured  as default, not connected with my localhost 8545 node. What do you mean by overwriting web3 ? I just consume the injection directly in js :/
For instance I retrieve my metamask account with web3.eth.getAccounts or web3.eth.accounts, I don't change its value.